# SWTBot in headless mode and java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError

Tags: eclipse, jenkins, swt, eclipse-rcp, swtbot

We meet the following problem. In case we try to excute our automated test suite unde Jenkins management we receive java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError in test that work with keyboard. Executing tests unde Jenkins control means that SWTBot in headless mode.  Our target platform is Windows 10. According to SWTBot developer notes the headless mode is not tested under windows. We use SWTBot version 2.2.1. In case we execute SWTBot test suite on remote vitual machine without Jenkins. This issue is not observed. Also our investigation show us that this issue can be reproduced on local machine in case keyboard layout is not found. So, I suppose the root cause of this issue is missing physical keyboard in this case. Also we take into consideration java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError says us that something wrong occures in initialization static variables

My investigation demonstrated that this issue is occured when test tries to push a key. Partially this problem can be resolved by using setText method instead of typeText. But we have set of tests that verify processing of keyboard combination like Alt+A or pushing Enter for example.

The application under testing is Eclipse RCP application that based on very old Eclipse platform (version 3.6)

Answer (score 0):

According to advices from SWTBot forum. ([SWTBot Forum topic](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/m/1797866/#msg_1797866)) The following line of code

```
SWTBotPreferences.KEYBOARD_LAYOUT = "EN_US";
```

resolves this issue. This line is inserted in method that has annotation @BeforeTest